# How to get a job on a different stage in azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

i have something like this in my azure pipeline

```
pool:
  name: name
  vmImage: Image

stages:
  stage: 1
    jobs:
     job: 1
     job: 2
     job: 3
  stage: 2
    condition: will run if stage 1 on job 2 is successful
  stage: 3
    condition: will run if job 1 or 3 in stage 1 is successful or stage 
               2 is successful
```

can I get the job 1 or 3 in stage 1? or can I do a

```
  (dependencies.stage3.job1.result,"Succeeded")
```

like code?

Comment: So, do you want `stage 2` will not run if `stage 1` failed? or only of job 1 or 3 failed but 2 is ok?

Comment: on stage 3. i would like to have an or condition because the stage 2 will skip if job 1 and 3 will run, it will only run if job 2 on stage 1 is successful. i would like to rule out job 2 on stage 1 in stage 3

Answer (score 0):

> How to get a job on a different stage in azure pipeline

You could add a task for `job1`,`job2`,`job3` to set veriables for each job, like:

```
  - task: InlinePowershell@1
    displayName: 'SetVariableInJobA'
    inputs:
      Script: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JobA;isOutput=true]true"'
    name: JobAResult
```

Then we could set the condition based on the variables from the job1 to job3 in the stage1 by the syntax `stageDependencies.stageName.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']`.

Please check the document [Jobs can access output variables from previous stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#jobs-can-access-output-variables-from-previous-stages) for some more details.

So, my final test YAML file looks like:

```
stages:
  - stage: A
    jobs:
    - job: jobA
      steps:
      - script: echo "This is JobA"
      - task: InlinePowershell@1
        displayName: 'SetVariableInJobA'
        inputs:
          Script: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JobA;isOutput=true]true"'
        name: JobAResult

    - job: jobB
      steps:
      - script: echo "This is JobB"
      - task: InlinePowershell@1
        displayName: 'SetVariableInJobB'
        inputs:
          Script: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JobB;isOutput=true]No"'
        name: JobBResult

    - job: jobC
      steps:
      - script: echo "This is JobC"
      - task: InlinePowershell@1
        displayName: 'SetVariableInJobC'
        inputs:
          Script: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JobC;isOutput=true]true"'
        name: JobCResult


  - stage: B
    variables:
      testB: $[ stageDependencies.A.jobB.outputs['JobBResult.JobB']]
    
    jobs:     
    - job: 
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.testB, 'Yes'))
      steps:
      - task: InlinePowershell@1
        inputs:
          Script: 'Write-Output ''$(testB)'''


  - stage: C
    variables:
      testA: $[ stageDependencies.A.jobA.outputs['JobAResult.JobA']]
      testB: $[ stageDependencies.A.jobB.outputs['JobBResult.JobB']]
      testC: $[ stageDependencies.A.jobC.outputs['JobCResult.JobC']]
    jobs:
    - job: 
      condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables.testA, 'Yes'), or(eq(variables.testB, 'Yes'), eq(variables.testC, 'Yes'))))
      steps:
      - task: InlinePowershell@1
        inputs:
          Script: 'Write-Output ''hello world'''
```

**Note:**

We could not set the condotion on the stage level directly, that is because the  variable `$[ stageDependencies.A.jobA.outputs['JobAResult.JobA']]` is compile variable, and the varibale we set by the task is runtime variable.